# Как составить структуру SQL БД для объекта с заранее неизвестным числом вложенных объектов?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

**Задача:**

Создать `SQL` БД со списком объектов, представляющих собой вопросы с заранее неизвестным числом переводов на заранее неизвестное число языков. Также переводы должны иметь свойства типа `Одобрено` Если бы это был JSON, то это выглядело бы так:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "translations": {
      "ru": {
        "translation": "русский перевод",
        "approved": true
      },
      "en": {
        "translation": "english translation",
        "approved": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "translations": {
      "ru": {
        "translation": "русский перевод",
        "approved": true
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Возможные решения:**

1. Таблица с колонками для каждого языка. В ячейках могут быть `null` для к-л языка вместо перевода, представляющего из-себя ID из другой таблицы 
   с переводами на определённый язык. Мне не нравится это, т.к. при добавлении нового языка надо править таблицу, добавляя колонку.
2. Таблица с 2 колонками - ID и имеющиеся переводы через запятую (`ru, en`) и таблица с 3 колонками - ID, язык, id вопроса из таблицы 1. Этот вариант мне не нравится необходимостью резать программно массив на строки-языки.

**Вопрос:**

Как спроектировать БД для такого случая правильно?

Comment: Нужна всего одна таблица: `(id, код_языка, текст_перевода, одобренность)`. По вкусу можно добавить ещё суррогатный ключ, дабы исбежать составного PK(id, код_языка).

Comment: @Fat-Zer, имеете в виду типа так: `id (auto_increment primary key), id_вопроса (max(id_вопроса) + 1), код_языка, текст_перевода, одобренность `? Мне кажется неудобным вручную высчитывать ID для новых вопросов... Или я не так понял?

Comment: да, если говорить про суррогатный ключ... значение для `id_вопроса` на своё усмотрение, и, по обстоятельствам, вероятно стоит добавить уникальный индекс на `(id_вопроса, код_языка)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал две таблицы.

В первой `id` и `идентификатор`.

Во второй `id`, `translation`, `lang_code` и `approved`.

Соответственно запрос будет:

```
SELECT translation FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 USING(id) WHERE ident = '...' AND lang_code = "en" AND approved = true;
```

Comment: А если мне хочется автоматической генерации ID для вопросов, то в первой таблице будет всего одна колонка - собственно ID? И во второй колонка для ID собственно записи не нужно?

Comment: Если вы оставите одну таблицу, вы не поймёте какую конкретно сущность вы переводите.

Comment: А id можно и нужно генерировать автоматически для первой таблицы. Во второй уникальным будет связка id - lang_code

Comment: Спасибо, это вроде рабочий вариант, но мне всё ещё непонятно зачем 2 ID в первой таблице и что вы имеете в виду под `голос «за»
тревога
Если вы оставите одну таблицу, вы не поймёте какую конкретно сущность вы переводите.`?

Comment: Ну допустим у вас есть какая то сущность. Неважно какая. Вы даёте ей некое кодовое имя.(Удобно потом будет писать функции, зная только кодовое имя можно будет получить перевод на нужном языке), а id нужен только для базы данных и связи двух таблиц.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, первая таблица тут абсолютно не нужна: только бессмысленная строгая связь один к одному.... или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Один ко многим. У одного id из первой может быть много переводов на разные языки

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ваш вариант с одной таблицей меня сильно смущает необходимостью самостоятельно высчитывать `id_вопроса`, тогда как вариант с 2 таблицами позволяет просто автоинкремент использовать)

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, всё ещё не понятно) Вы имеете в виду какой-то человекочитаемый ID для вопроса чисто для наглядности в таблицу добавляемый? Типа текст вопроса на первом добавленном переводе?

Comment: Ну хотя бы и так. Вам ведь нужно понимать что вы конкретно переводите. Просто представьте как будете запрашивать информацию из базы не зная этого идентификатора.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, вроде идею понял, но в моём случае первый перевод может быть на польском и для меня этот ID будет бессмысленным набором букв, если его не переводить автоматически при первой записи в БД - но тут надо будет сетевые запросы к API делать, что, кажется, уже сильно излишне)

Comment: Тогда встречный вопрос. А как вы тогда разделяете что вот этот вопрос - это вот этот вопрос? Извините за тафтологию.

Comment: @УстьянцевБорис, ну, вроде, для различения вопросов достаточно будет `id`. Или я не правильно ваш вопрос понял? Я вряд ли буду делать запросы данных из таблицы 1 без присоединения данных из таблицы 2.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74877/discussion-between---and-).